# Spring webflow view resolver config: subfolders for JSP Files

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-webflow-2

Using Spring webflow and in the serlvet-configuration I have this for JSP files:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

and this for flow XML files:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry"
    flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/WEB-INF/flows/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

Due to the `/**/`, any flow XML file in may they be in sub directory or not is resolved automatically so I need not specify the subfolder in the flow definition.
For JSP `**` does seem not work.

Is there a way to do the same? I'd like to use subdirectories, because it makes it look cleaner when don't have to scroll through a heap of JSP files in the package explorer. On the other hand, If I have to specify the subdirectory each time, it's probably prone to getting typos not being detected

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to specify ant style wildcard in 'prefix' or 'suffix' attribute.

As you said, you can specify the path in the flow definition as below

```
<view-state id="showSearchCriteria" view="customer/search">
    <transition on="lookupCriteriaEntered" to="searchCustomer" />
</view-state>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not an elegant solution but you can try jsps in multiple subfolders of jsp folder using tiles as:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
          <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tilesDef.xml</value>
            </list>
          </property>
    </bean>
```

Define your tilesDef.xml as:

```
    <tiles-definitions>     
        <definition name="page1" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/subFolder1/page1.jsp"/>
        <definition name="page2" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/subFolder2/page2.jsp"/>
    </tiles-definitions>
```

In your controller return as:

```
    new ModelAndView("page1");
```

or as:

```
    new ModelAndView("page2");
```

But the drawback of this would be that you cannot have 2 jsps with same name in different folders as the definition name is unique.